# RuntimeError: "softmax_lastdim_kernel_impl" not implemented for 'Half' site:stackoverflow.com

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I'm following the steps as outlined in the Colab Disco Diffusion v5.xx (tried multiple versions with the same effect) - Warp by Alex Spirin.
https://colab.research.google.com/github/Sxela/DiscoDiffusion-Warp/blob/main/Disco_Diffusion_v5_2_Warp.ipynb

I did make a copy to my Google Drive and I uploaded a video and followed instructions as given in this YouTube video (I watched alternative videos as well to make sure that I didn't miss something):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaX4XMq0vVo&t=318s

I used to get a slightly different error and that led me to follow this advice here:

https://github.com/alembics/disco-diffusion/issues/130#issuecomment-1281757126

Now I'm getting this error:

````
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-1c79d8e6a9d5> in <module>
    216 torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    217 try:
--> 218     do_run()
    219 except KeyboardInterrupt:
    220     pass

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in softmax(input, dim, _stacklevel, dtype)
   1678         dim = _get_softmax_dim("softmax", input.dim(), _stacklevel)
   1679     if dtype is None:
-> 1680         ret = input.softmax(dim)
   1681     else:
   1682         ret = input.softmax(dim, dtype=dtype)

RuntimeError: "softmax_lastdim_kernel_impl" not implemented for 'Half'```
````

Answer (score 2):

Just call `.float()` on the tensor. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`torch.FloatTensor` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Torch CPU backend doesn't have a softmax implementation. You either convert the input tensor to float32 or move the tensor to GPU by `.cuda()`